# Trying to navigate between states/views without reloading controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use angular-ui-router to navigate through states without reloading the controller and view. I.e. if I'm in **app.posts** and I navigate to **app.postId** using an href and click back button in the browser, the app.posts view should appear and the state should be as it was before. Currently the state is reloaded as if it was opened for the first time.

Also html5mode is enabled on the $locationProvider.

The states are defined as

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

$stateProvider
.state('app.home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: 'js/main/templates/home.html',
  controller: 'HomeCtrl'
})

.state('app.posts', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'js/PostList/PostList.html',
  controller: 'PostListCtrl',
  deepStateRedirect: true
})
.state('app.postId', {
  url: '/post/:id',
  templateUrl: 'js/Post/Post.html',
  controller: 'PostViewCtrl'
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true, requireBase:false});
```

Answer (score 1):

The only time a controller result does not re-initialize is if you are going *back* to a parent state.

There's an in-depth conversation about this here: [Caching URL view/state with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591335/caching-url-view-state-with-parameters)